# how to work with ODS files in a java application

Tags: java

You need to read the ODS file and then make changes to it in the java application. Apache POI does not solve the problem. throws the error org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]. the solution must be from openSource. Thank you

tried to use Apache POI. throws the error org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]. GPT suggests using Apache POI but it doesn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46468272/how-to-read-ods-document-by-java-and-jopendocument-package

Comment: https://www.jopendocument.org/index.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.